# Accessing elements of class="input-append"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, append

I'm using `class="input-append"` in `<tr>` so each row contains different inputs, and i have a button to append new inputs row,

```html
<tr class="input-append">
  <td>
    <span>Person {{$index+1}}</span>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Time From: <input type="text" ng-model="person.name"> Age: <input type="text" ng-model="person.age">    
  </td> 
</tr>
```

for example:
ID,Name,Age , when i click the button a new row will be added. how i can access the inputs in javascript ?!! for example i want to access the Age in the second row.

regards.

Comment: just select input-append and get the value of age from the second td element ? Or 4th td element as you have one containing a span and the other is the headers i am guessing ?

Comment: thanks, i mean i want to use  document.getElementById( '' ).value; how i can access the elements of each row using something like that ?!

Comment: just use document.getElementsByClassName('input-append')[0] < that will get the container and then get the second td element. So > document.getElementsByClassName('input-append')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[1] < that will get second 'td' element then use tthis to get the value of what you wish

Comment: It seems that you use **angularJS** so why don't you use it for get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use document.getElementsByClassName() and QuerySelector

```
trs = document.getElementsByClassName("input-append");

personName = trs[1].querySelector("input[ng-model='person.name']").value;
personAge = trs[1].querySelector("input[ng-model='person.age']").value;
```

and your html

```
<table>  
<tr class="input-append" >
<td>
<span>Person {{$index+1}}</span></td>
<td align="center">Time From: <input type="text"  ng-model="person.name">  Age: <input type="text"  ng-model="person.age">  
</td>   
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="input-append" >
<td>
<span>Person {{$index+1}}</span></td>
<td align="center">Time From: <input type="text"  ng-model="person.name" value="testName">  Age: <input type="text"  ng-model="person.age" value="testAge">  
</td>   
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

See demo: http://jsbin.com/xemehoxono/edit?html,js,output